# Old CSS is Showing up When I change the Page

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, ckeditor

I am working on a website which include React CKEditor 4. I don't like its style so I've changed its CSS and made it look better. It's been used in different part of my website. When I first started the page on localhost, it is shown with the CSS changes I made. However, when I changed the page which also has CKEditor 4, it comes with the original styling. When I refresh the page, it turns into the version I made. There are similar Stackoverflow questions and they say that CSS cache may cause that. I've tried Ctrl + shift + R to clean it up but it did not work. I've also tried different browsers. I have the same problem and could not figured it out why.

Comment: Add the code involved in this issue, not all your code, just the relevant parts.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably facing a problem with the cache of the browsers.

You can try generating random names of the files for every build of your website in order to by-pass the caches. This can be done automatically with any modern build system for js websites.

You can take a look at https://webpack.js.org